# How to put website links in "Used literature" slide of the presentation?

Tags: presentation, online-resource

I'm preparing a presentation for my class. Last slide should be the list of resources I've used for the material, e.g.

> Sherwani N., Algorithms for VLSI Physical Design Automation, Kluwer Academic Publishers, Dordrecht 2002, -C.1, -P.1-15

I've also used some Wikipedia material. How should I write it? Like this?

> Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_design_(electronics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Websites change. You should include information such as time, date, version, etc.

For Wikipedia in particular, you can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia#Examples_of_how_to_cite_Wikipedia

For general websites, similar ideas apply. Remember to appropiately cite dates, author names, and possibly also titles for the website content (e.g., if it's a blog article, the blog title should be included). Never just post a link, that's horrible style.

Comment: by the way, I'm not an English speaker and my presentation is in my native language. When referencing the topic, e.g. `"Physical Design": Wikipedia...`, etc. Should I write these in English or my native language?

Comment: For general websites, also make sure to archive the website on [archive.org](https://archive.org/) and [archive.is](https://archive.is/) and any other similar places you're aware of.

Comment: @user3132457 Use the language of the site itself. In some cases, I have seen translations added along with the original title, but I am from a country where English is well-understood so I am not sure how common that is.